# What is the standard way to describe the paths to config files of my ruby application (linux)?

Tags: ruby

What is the standard way to describe the paths to config files of my ruby application (linux)? (not rails, but I think it doesn't matter right now)

How does this "fit" into standard paths like `/etc/` and `/usr/local/etc/`?
Let's say I want to put config in /usr/local/etc/myapp/config.json during global installation,
but in `$HOME/.config/myapp/config.json` during local installation.

I want to provide the default configuration file with my application, not pass it from somewhere else (although this is also possible, but only as an option).

Can gemspec do this? I found in the description of Gem::Specification only paths to bin and exe files, but not to configuration files.

Comment: In general there has been a step away from YAML/JSON towards using Ruby for configuration. Its not like Java where the language is so clunky so that even XML seems appealing. Libraries (such as gems) define configuration with a pretty standard  [`MyModule.configure` pattern](https://medium.com/@vfreefly/the-most-simple-configuration-block-implementation-for-a-ruby-gem-815fe1dad5dc) which applications then can customize in bootstrappers or intializers. This is mostly completely OS agnostic.

Comment: Thank you, @max! In my question, the type of the config file is not at all important.
Let it be config.rb or settings.rb with "standard MyModule.configure pattern".Where to put it?
Can I put it in /usr/local/etc/myapp/config.rb or $HOME/.config/myapp/config.rb?
or is it ruby antipattern?

Comment: I wouldn't say that its an anti-pattern but you rarely want to put any configuration anywhere except the lib code (the gem), the application, or the environment (env vars, docker config) if we are talking about something like a web application. If its a command line tool then you're writing then yes maybe user config in`$HOME`  but otherwise its just quirky and irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks! In this particular case, yes, I am writing a command line tool.
But I would like to understand what is more correct (ruby way?) in general.